# How to: put definition of figures together, then generate picture at different places

Tags: floats, input

A little explanation: For better writing experience, I want to organize all definition (I mean `\begin{figure}...` stuff) of figures into one file, and `\input` it to my main `.tex`, then generate the picture at the places where I want to.

I don't know if it's possible, but it will be quite convenient if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? In this one we put all the figure definitions in file `myfigs.tex`, input this file to the main file and then use the definitions at relevant places.

**Main File**

```
\documentclass{article}

% Use lipsum package for dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\input myfigs.tex

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\figone

\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]

\figtwo

\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]

\figthree


\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]

\figfour

\end{document}
```

**`myfigs.tex`**

```
\def\figone{\begin{figure}[[!tbp]]
  \centering
  Figure One
  \caption{Figure one.}
  \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}}


\def\figtwo{\begin{figure}[[!tbp]]
  \centering
  Figure Two
  \caption{Figure two.}
  \label{fig:two}
\end{figure}}



\def\figthree{\begin{figure}[[!tbp]]
  \centering
  Figure Three
  \caption{Figure three.}
  \label{fig:three}
\end{figure}}



\def\figfour{\begin{figure}[[!tbp]]
  \centering
  Figure Four
  \caption{Figure four.}
  \label{fig:four}
\end{figure}}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Wrote a general purpose macro to define figure definitions.

**`myfigs.tex`**

```
% #1 Definition name
% #2 Position specifier
% #3 Actual figure
% #4 Caption
% #5 Label
\long\def\figdef#1#2#3#4#5{\long\gdef#1{\begin{figure}[#2]
    \centering#3\caption{#4}\label{#5}\end{figure}}}

\figdef{\figone}{!tbp}{Figure One}{Figure one.}{fig:one}
\figdef{\figtwo}{!tbp}{Figure Two}{Figure two.}{fig:two}
\figdef{\figthree}{!tbp}{Figure Three}{Figure three.}{fig:three}
\figdef{\figfour}{!tbp}{Figure Four}{Figure four.}{fig:four}
```

The main file is unchanged.

Comment: yes, exactly. `\def` works quite well, while I can't believe these is no native support in Latex (or other packages) for this instead of a manmade `\def`.

Comment: @ColinZ Perhaps the reason is there are so many parameters and controls involved. I got tempted to write a simple generic macro to be called again and again with all the picture parameters inside the definition file, and then use the definitions in the same way as we have done here. Anyway, since this has worked, you can accept and upvote my answer. :-)

Comment: @ColinZ Could not overcome the temptation to write  a _(somewhat)_  general purpose one. See the UPDATE.

Comment: Note that in case the figure content or caption crosses paragraph breaks, you need to define the macros `\long`. LaTeX's `\newcommand` defines macros `\long` by default, which is just another reason to prefer it over `\def` in user macros.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. If you have  your, say, figure.tex organized as follows:

```
\def\myfigI{\begin{figure} (your first figure} \end{figure}}
\def\myfigII{\begin{figure} (your second figure} \end{figure}}
```

then, after `\input`ing this file, you can use in your main file simply names: `\myfigI`, `\myfigII` and so on, in places where you want to.

Comment: @Scherwent Exactly what I want to do, but the same question to MMA: is these native support in Latex (or other packages) for this instead of a manmade `\def`?

Comment: @ColinZ It is probably not an answer that you are expecting, but: producing your own macros is a necessary condition to taste the sweetness of TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: @ColinZ You could make your life a little bit easier with defining a “store” macro and a “load” macro so that you are allowed to use more characters than just `a-zA-Z`. You could then add key-value support for options (i.e. more control over things like captions and figures and optional arguments) but that’s about that. There are probably a few packages that support some kind of databasing (like `datatool`) but the setup would probably be harder than just defining two or three macros.